# Checking if my element in a DataFrame is in another list in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a manipulation similar to the below:

```
x<-c(1:10)
df<-data.frame(x)
df['y']<-NA
intersections<-c(3,6,9)
values<-c('hello','hi','bye')
inset<-data.frame(intersections,values)
df['y']<-ifelse(df['x'] %in% inset$intersections, inset$values,NA)
```

I would like my output to look like:

```
df
x, y
1, NA
2, NA
3, 'hello'
4, NA
5, NA
6, 'hi'
7, NA
8, NA
9, 'bye'
```

Any pointers please?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the following in your code and it works

```
inset <- data.frame(intersections,values, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$y <- ifelse(df$x %in% inset$intersections, inset$values, NA )
```

Comment: I like the elegance of your solution, can you explain what stringsAsFactors does? Thanks

Comment: values would be set as a factor if you just create the dataframe inset. The ifelse would then just enter a 1 instead of the text value. By setting stringAsFactors to FALSE you avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using ifelse, try this:

```
merge(df, inset, all.x = TRUE, by.x = "x", by.y = "intersections") -> df$y
```

Comment: In reality my X is 10s of thousands of rows, and Y is only a handful (~8) - but those values are repeated (and dates). Is merge really the easiest way to tackle this?

Thanks

Comment: there are many ways to solve this - merge is just one. computational time is not an issue here - your data set is still relatively small.

Comment: I agree, computational time is not important here. I will give it a go - it's slightly obfuscated by dates (etc).